# how to convert date according to time zones

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

So in my project a user from USA set some time say it was 10:30 am
and now when a person some another country see that time then it should be according to their timezone .

For Example in USA it is 5:30 am now 
and in india it is 6:30 pm , so if after 5 hours a person in india sees that then that person should see 6:30 pm for that post

Comment: Time should be converted to UTC before sent to server, so that times can be converted by local timezone information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the below function to solve this problem.
How it works: suppose this was your local time converted to GMT zero - 2016-04-14 21:00:00 +0000

and when I convert it using following function, I'm here in New Delhi India, which has GMT+05:30, then I will get time 2:30 of morning.

```
+(NSString*)getLocalTimeFromGMTzero : (NSString*)GMTzerioTimeString {

    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];    

    //Create the date assuming the given string is in GMT
    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:GMTzerioTimeString];

    //Create a date string in the local timezone
    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];
    NSString *localDateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"date = %@", localDateString);

    return localDateString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php function `gmdate()`
string gmdate(string $format[,int $timestamp= time()] )
Identical to the date()function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
Parameters format The format of the outputted date string. See the formatting options for the date() function. timestamp The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In other words, it defaults to the value of time().Return Values Returns a formatted date string. If a non-numeric value is used for timestamp, FALSE is returned and an E_WARNING level error is emitted.
in timestamp add the interval to.
Ex if GMT zone is 5 say then add timestamp+5*60*60

Comment: The OP mention the client side only (iOS and Swift in tags), so it'd be better to explain the problem from the client side perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function:

```
    class func getDateWithFormat(format: String) -> NSDate {
    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    var newDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
    return newDate
}
```

> Eg: var todaysDate: NSDate = NSDate.getDateWithFormat("dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss a")

Comment: It's better to refer to some widely used standard for date and time formatting, like ISO 8601 (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or this [w3c page](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)).

Comment: so how it supposed to work
can you explain
have you tried it yourself ?

Comment: this function will give you the time with timezone (present in phone settings) with provided format.